# Function filter resize dimensions returning black images in wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I'm currently running the following code to resize the images I upload into 200x300 px, but there must be something wrong on it, since it's saving a 200x300 file which is completely black. Which correction have I to do?

```
function filter_image_resize_dimensions( $payload, $orig_w, $orig_h, $dest_w, $dest_h, $crop ) {
    if ( $orig_h > 1 ) {
        $new_w = 200;
        $new_h = 300;
    }

    return array( 0, 0, (int) $s_x, (int) $s_y, (int) $new_w, (int) $new_h, (int) $crop_w, (int) $crop_h );
}
add_filter( 'image_resize_dimensions', 'filter_image_resize_dimensions', 10, 6 );
```

Comment: if your `$orig_h` is smaller than 200, you have no values for `$new_w` and `$new_h`.

Comment: That's okay, but I'm using as a test, a 2500x2000 image. And that's generating black photo on that. So it's not the case you mentioned.